# SVG files not displaying with Cloudberry PSSnapIn

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, svg, cloudberry

I am uploading a folder with subfolders containg SVG files. MIME-Type is set to image/svg+xml.

When I transfer the folder using the Cloudberry GUI interface there is no problem and the publication with the SVG files display perfectly.

When I transfer the same folder using PowerShell with the Cloudberry PSSnapIn with -CheckFileConsistency set. the folder uploads but the SVG files do not render.

I believe that the files with the snap-in are being handled as 'octet-stream'  whilst those transferred manually are being handled correctly as svg+xml.  I've tried transferring with TNTDrive and again the files display with no issue.

Comment: Please post your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), at the moment we don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer.  Not enough to set the .svg content-type using the Cloudberry GUI.  You have to set it in the PS script as well using Add-CloudContentType.